# Is there a way to pass an expected json model (which can change depending on whats needed) to an API and return a response with that model populated?

Tags: c#, json, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Apologies if the question is a bit vague but ill try word it as best I can.
Lets say we have an API POST endpoint which accepts a json structure as the body and returns a json. This request json structure can always be different depending on what is required but will always be within the scope of a large generic model.
For example, I pass to the API this json as the body:

```
"[ { 
"Name": "x", 
"Id": 0, 
"Documents" : 
 { "name": "x",
   "id": 0
 },  
}, ]"
```

Lets say on the API side I have a large Model consisting of the classes/parameters below which is fully populated via another service:

```
var auth = new List<Author>();
auth = AuthService.GetAuthDetails();
```

Model:

```
public class Author
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set;}
    public List<Documents> Documents {get; set;}
}

public class Documents {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way I can Serialize the 'auth' object using the structure passed to the API to only return those data points which are needed (e.g State, and PostalCode are not needed in the response)?

Comment: it should be possible. did you tried something which did not worked.

Comment: well i tried one method of serializing the request json to a dynamic json object and trying to find a way to use that use that as the type for deserialization but that hasnt worked. E.g. JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<serializedDynamicObject>(auth);

Comment: Your json is not valid. And your class  contains documents property as a list , but json documents are an object. This is a problem. Fix or class or json.

Comment: A possible approach would be to 1) only fill properties having to be set, according to your json, in the model (or remove the ones you don't want if they have been set) and 2) configure your serializer to NOT emit properties having a value being default (default being null for most types).

Comment: What serializer are you using?  Json.NET?  System.Text.Json?  Something else?

Comment: Hi @mrhmanners, firstly, how do you get the response json? Are you sure it is correct? For your json data, it does not match the model at all. The correct json should be: `[ {"Name": "x","Id": 0, "Documents" : [{"name": "x","id": 0}] } ]`. Then, for your requirement, do you mean your json file  dynamically contain the model property value? If so, it can deserilize correctlly. But the Documents corresponding json should be array `[]`. Or you mean the json is correct and you want to deserialize the current model?